# Integrating UFT 14.0 & Selenium Automation test cases

Tags: oracle, selenium, automation, automated-tests, hp-uft

We have 2 clinical applications one is a patient administration created in Oracle forms and another clinical application which is a Java based application. We are in the process of automating the applications to do end to end testing. we have been able to automate the Oracle forms application part in UFT 14.0 and we have been able to automate the Java side in selenium both of these in isolation of each other.

Is there anyway of integrating UFT & Selenium so that we can complete end to end automation testing, so that when we have completed the UFT testing it then goes onto complete the selenium test cases.

Comment: Why not automate the Java part in UFT too?

Comment: Hi Motti, thanks for your reply I am quite a newbie to UFT, Could you give me some pointers or if you know of any on line links i could refer to, Thanks

Comment: I don't have any specific pointers, there are plenty of tutorials online

Answer (score 1):

UFT is a very powerful tool and you can surely do end to end testing with it. The only reason to test using selenium is if you are trying to use open source tool. With UFT you can record an play back scripts (end to end scenarios) I dont recommend record and play back as it not dynamic but its a way to start. You can also test backend(databases) with fronend(User interface). There are a lot of Youtube videos that you can check out.

[UFT Step by Step tutoriols](https://www.guru99.com/quick-test-professional-qtp-tutorial.html)

[UFT youtube link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ak8j7lzYXJk)

Hope this will help you start
good luck!!!

Answer (score 0):

Other Option can be, to Create Executable file for the selenium Test Cases and Trigger them from UFT at required stage.

Comment: do you have an example of this?